# PHP variables into XML

Tags: php, xml, variables

Please help me, for example I have next one:

```
<php?
$phone = "7777111111";
$src = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<SMS> 
<sender>Blabla</sender>    
<text>Hello</text>   
</message>    
<numbers> 
<number messageID="msg11"> HERE MUST BE NUMBER!!!</number> 
</numbers>   
</SMS>;

$Curl = curl_init();    
$CurlOptions = array(   
CURLOPT_URL=>'http://atompark.com/members/sms/xml.php',  
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>false,   
CURLOPT_POST=>true,  
CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,   
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,    
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>15,  
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>100,    
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array('XML'=>$src),   
);  
?>
```

How can I put variable $phone into tags  in XML?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have just either googled that or you could spend some time reading some [very basic introduction to PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp).

```
<?php
$phone = "7777111111";
$src = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<SMS> 
<sender>Blabla</sender>    
<text>Hello</text>   
</message>    
<numbers> 
<number messageID="msg11">' . $phone . '</number> 
</numbers>   
</SMS>;

$Curl = curl_init();    
$CurlOptions = array(   
CURLOPT_URL=>'http://atompark.com/members/sms/xml.php',  
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>false,   
CURLOPT_POST=>true,  
CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,   
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,    
CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>15,  
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>100,    
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array('XML'=>$src),   
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong.

- You are closing "`</message>`" without opening.
- You must close the $src string with a ' before ;
- PHP open tag is `<?php` not `<php?`

also you could use DOMDocument object to create this kind of XML very easily.

And about your question, string concatenation :

```
$name = "Foo";
$welcome = "Hello ".$name;
echo($welcome); // will output "Hello Foo"
```

So, correct code is :

```
<?php
    $phone = "7777111111";
    $src = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<SMS>
  <message>
    <sender>Blabla</sender>    
    <text>Hello</text>   
  </message>    
  <numbers> 
    <number messageID="msg11">'.$phone.'</number> 
  </numbers>   
</SMS>';

    $Curl = curl_init();    
    $CurlOptions = array(   
        CURLOPT_URL=>'http://atompark.com/members/sms/xml.php',  
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION=>false,   
        CURLOPT_POST=>true,  
        CURLOPT_HEADER=>false,   
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,    
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>15,  
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>100,    
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=>array('XML'=>$src),   
    );
```

Apolo

Comment: Why should he do the `$Curl = curl_init();` Part two times?